# Use of anonymous function shows up as unknown type

Tags: php, function, types, anonymous

When I attempt to use an anonymous function in PHP (As an available callback), there are no syntactical errors or the like but when I attempt to execute the callback, it errors out outputting that the function must be named. gettype returns a null value.

Anyone have any experience with this?

http://pastie.org/1088386

Answer (score 2):

It [gives](http://codepad.viper-7.com/THv7xH) `object` to me, which is correct because closures are implemented as objects of type `Closure`.

There are know memory corruption issues with closures and some opcode caches. If you are using one, disable it and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Same here, `object` on PHP 5.3, Windows 7